# How to import a python module from a relative path?

Tags: python, python-import, pythonpath

I've got the following file structure:
[image]

I'm trying to initialize some objects in `main.py` that belong to modules in the `Listener`, `Parser` and `Configurations` folders.

I understand I can't just write `import listener` since it's not in the same path.
What simple ways are there for the imports to work without adding the paths to the `PYTHONPATH` env variable?
Is there a way to make it work on any machine "out of the box" without the need to add the paths to `PYTHONPATH` or any solution like that? Preferably something with a relative path like in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

In short, you need to programmatically define `PYTHONPATH` in `main.py`, something like:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

This implicitly adds current directory to `PYTHONPATH`. Rest of the part is straightforward

Create `__init__.py` file in each of the directories. After that, each of the modules can be imported as `from Listener import ...` or `from Misc import ...` etc.

The approach works 'out of box' without redefining any environmental variable.

Comment: This answer doesn't answer how to import from two level above directory. the ... is only for one leve. Any idea? THx