# Python 3 module relative import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I have got a problem with *relative import* while developing an application that contains two packages I implemented, one for functionality and other for GUI.

Here's the actual application "architecture" layout:

```
 main.py  
 functionality/  
     |__init__.py  
     |functionality.py  
     |config/  
         |__init__.py  
         |conf.py  
 gui/  
     |__init__.py  
     |gui.py
```

I import the `config` module inside the `functionality.py` file and use it without any problem. But when I import the functionality module to the `main.py` file and run it, I get the following error:

```
from config import conf
ImportError: No module named 'config'
```

I have searched for this problem and read several Python books, but I didn't find any solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing from a relative path in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from .config import conf` ?

Comment: `..` if my information serves me right

Comment: @wim It throws this error: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

Comment: @RNar The double dot before import statement takes you to one upper level in the hierarchy

Comment: .... thats what you are trying to do...?

Comment: @RNar Yes, definitely that's what I want to do. I tried it but it throws the same error as I mentioned in my first comment

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you, you tried to import functionality.functionality, which imports config, and that fails.

That's because when you run main.py, in your module search path there is no modules containing anything like 'config'. Check that out: add

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

right before you imported functionality. There is root in your search path (where main.py is located) and some default site directories.

Refer to this section: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

As it written there, you have to use relative imports (with leading dots) or write full path (functionality.config in your case)

Comment: You are right, I should use relative imports and that's what works, the full path solution also works. The second solution throws another error: __ImportError: No module named 'functionality.config'; 'functionality' is not a package__

Comment: Yes, you can't directly use a module with a local import.

Comment: Also, I should specify that those errors occur when I run _functionality.py_ alone; unlike _main.py_ which runs fine even with importing functionality package.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution!

I added a leading dot the faulty import statement in *functionality.py* file:

```
from .config import conf
```

It works just fine when running the *main.py* file!
But let's say that I reversed the problem because now the import doesn't work when I run the *functionality.py* alone the interpreter throws the same exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/youssef/workspace/application/functionality/functionality.py", line 14, in <module>
from .config import conf
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I must also mention that I emptied the *__init__.py* file that exists in the config package so it doesn't contain any import statement.

I thank you all for your efforts and if I find other solutions, I will edit this answer.