# In Python, how can I import from a grandparent folder with a relative path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-path

Imagine a folder structure as follows:

```
project/
    grandparent.py
    folder1/
        parent.py
        folder2/
            sibling.py
            current.py
```

If I am in `current.py` I can import from the other files [using relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506029/236081) as follows:

```
from .sibling import *
from ..parent import *
```

How can I import from `grandparent.py` ?

(I've tried `...grandparent` and `../..grandparent`  )

Comment: Make them python-packages, not common dir and you will be able use import like: import grandparent.folder1.parent

Comment: For clarification, @NickRyan is saying:  "do what ZYYYY says below".  That is all it takes to make a python package.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson perhaps edit that answer to include your helpful notes

Comment: Yep, you're right @d3vid .  Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Create a Python Package

As a means to ensure some level of security - so that Python modules cannot access areas where they are not welcome - importing from parents or grandparents is generally prohibited... *unless you create a package*.

Luckily, in Python, creating a package is *crazy-easy*.  You simply need to add a `__init__.py` file in each folder/directory that you want to treat as part of the package.  And, the `__init__.py` file ***doesn't even need to contain anything***.  You just need the (potentially empty) file to exist.

For instance:

```
#current.py

from folder1.grandparent import display

display()

#grandparent.py
def display():
    print("grandparent")

# ├── folder1
# │   ├── __init__.py
# │   ├── folder2
# │   │   ├── __init__.py
# │   │   └── folder3
# │   │       ├── __init__.py
# │   │       └── current.py
# │   └── grandparent.py
```

## Next Steps

This is not in the OP's question, but highly related and worth mentioning:  If you import a **directory** instead of a module (file), then you are importing the `__init__.py` file.  E.g.,

```
import folder1
```

actually performs an import of the `__init__.py` file in the `folder1` directory.

Lastly, the double-underscore is used so often, it's shortened to [*dunder*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dunder-magic-methods-python/).  So when speaking, you can say "dunder init" to refer to `__init__.py`.

Comment: To be clear, if someone is new: @ZYYYY added those `__init__.py` files at each folder level that is part of the package.  Those files can be **completely empty**, as long as they exist.  By adding them, you have made the package "traversable" and you can import as shown.  Final note:  with Python 3 in *some cases* you don't need to have the `__init__.py` files present.  But please use them; (a) it makes your code more friendly to legacy Python, (b) it is clear to others what is considered part of the package, and (c) even Python 3 cannot fully traverse, like in this grandparent case.

Comment: Does folder1 have to be in sys.path?

Comment: I tried the answer but it didn't work. But it did work after adding folder 1 to sys.path. Is this a mandatory step?

Answer (score -2):

## current.py

```
import os
import sys
FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH = os.path.abspath(__file__)  # get absolute filepath
CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(FILE_ABSOLUTE_PATH)  # get directory path of file
PARENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(CURRENT_DIR)  # get parent directory path
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PARENT_DIR)  # get grand parent directory path
# or you can directly get grandparent directory path as below
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)  # append the path to system
import grandparent
from folder1 import parent  # this way you can import files from parent directory too instead of again appending it to system path
```

Comment: Best not to be messing with **actual** path names, but to add the `__init__.py` files, as @ZYYY mentioned above.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson It's not messing with actual path, it's the way many modules prefer to use and not to worry about init file. If you look it's just a way to get current/parent directory of a file