# Calling python setup.py install from another directory

Tags: python, setup.py

I have the following arborescence:

```
- root_folder <--- I'm here
    - folder
        - setup.py
        - myModule
```

When I run `python setup.py install` from `folder`, myModule is installed properly and I can do `import myModule`.

Howerver, when I run `python folder/setup.py install` from `root_folder`, `import myModule` fails, I have to call `import folder.myModule`.

How can I call the `setup.py` script from another folder but keep the root folder to be the folder containing the `setup.py` file?

Comment: Hmm, AFAIK, `setup.py` expects to be called from the current directory. Calling it from a different directort may have unwanted and unpredictable effects.

Comment: Maybe related to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python

Comment: If you always want the root folder to be `folder` then you may mark the folder as [PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917492/how-to-use-pythonpath)

Comment: @Soumendra I'm installing multiple packages from different folders, so I'd prefer not setting the `PYTHONPATH` to `folder` here.

Comment: Okay, I think you will be calling `setup.py` only from the `root_folder` and never directly run the standalone `setup.py` file, so what's wrong in `import folder.myModule` ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `folder.myModule`, I simply want another behaviour.

Comment: did you find solution at the end?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can run a `setup.py` in a different directory by executing Python in a subprocess.

For example, if the folder in which you want to run the `setup.py` is `C:\Program Files\foo`, then you can use:

```
$ python -c "import subprocess,os; os.chdir('C:\Program Files\foo'); subprocess.call(['python','setup.py','install'])"
```