# Python import VIsual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, python-import

I'm trying to import a class from a file, but I can't find the right syntax in Visual Studio Code :i

My structure:

```
└── src
    ├── common
    │   ├── database.py
    │  
    └── models
        ├── admin
              ├──admin.py
```

In admin.py, I need to import a class called `Database`, which is located in database.py. My solution would be:

```
from src.common.database import Database
```

But then I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dave in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506029/2053706, you can use relative references to other files on import.

What you're looking for is:

```
from ...src.common.database import Database
```

Each "dot" is one path back, except the first "dot" which is "this folder".

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I does make sense.. But when i use this syntax, i get ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Comment: With two dots, i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models.src'

Comment: you might need to declare the "src" folder with absolute paths as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54997388/2053706