# How do I import a file that is in another directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
-Booking
    -components
        -db.py
    -scripts
        -insert_data.py
```

How do I import db.py in insert_data.py?
(I'm using python 3)

Comment: Where is your current working directory? Where are you trying to import the script to?

Comment: `components` needs an [`__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

Answer (score 0):

`from components import db`

Should work as long as `components` has a (potentially empty) `__init__.py` in it

Answer (score 0):

1. Put `__init__.py` inside `components` folder
2. Access it from `scripts` folder using `from ..components import db`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options, and it helps to know how Python's modules and packages work (which is not always completely straightforward and intuitive):

- [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948494/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-module-and-a-python-package)
- [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)
- [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)
- [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)
- [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html (even the official documentation can be helpful at times :)

One way is to explicitly modify the module search path in the beginning of your script:

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', 'components'))
import db
```

A less hacky way uses **relative import**, as described in [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python) and [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241420/execution-of-python-code-with-m-option-or-not).