# how to call different inside folder code to another folder code in python?

Tags: python

These is my folders. they are inside the parent folder

```
 programs -> parent folder
      program -> folder
         python_code.py
      program_two -> folder
         another_python_code.py
```

in another_python_code.py, I wrote code like this to call the python_code.py

```
from program.python_code import class_name
```

but I am getting an error saying

```
from program.python_code import class_name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'program'
```

I do have **init** file in both places

I am using python 3.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59257204/how-do-i-import-a-file-that-is-in-another-directory This was asked about 10 minutes ago...