# cannot import name 'player' from class files

Tags: python-3.x

Current File Structure

```
Game/
    __init__.py
    main.py

    Physics/
       __init__.py
       utils.py

    Models/
       __init__.py
       player.py
```

File Contents of Game/`__init__.py`

```
from Models import player
```

File Contents of Game/Physics/`__init__.py`

```
from ..Models import player
```

File Contents of Game/Models/`__init__.py`

```
class PlayerModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
```

File Contents of Game/Physics/`utils.py` -> Where error is occuring with `No Module named Game`

```
from Game import player # here is error?

def model_weapon_damage(weapon_model: player.Weapon):
    return weapon_model.base_damage

def model_armor_negation(armor_model: player.Armor, weapon_model: player.Weapon):
    weapon_damage = model_weapon_damage(weapon_model)
```

I have tried looking up how to import using the file structure, but i can't follow.
i am trying to give Game access to everything and have other class files be able to use the imports

Comment: cant you just use your import like you do in the init `from ..Models import player`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referencing everything from the project root (Game).

```
from Game.Models import player
```

The `__init__.py` files can be empty. They just tell python that it is a package directory.

Comment: Editing the utils.py from initial to
`from Game.Models import player`
and it stills returns same error