# How to import a self-coded python class from a higher-level directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have created a python class as well as a python script, which is suppossed to call this class. 
The entire code lies inside a `Code` folder, which contains a `Classes` and a `Scripts` folder.

The class is stored in:

```
Classes
    > myClass.py
```

Whereas the script is stored in:

```
Scripts
    > myScript.py
```

I try to call the class within my script, using:

```
from ..Classes.myClass import MY_CLASS
```

Now, the error message that I receive is: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

I think this is strange, as the two dots should indicate to python that my parent directory is one level up the hierarchy. But apparently I am missing out on sth crucial here. Is there an easy fix to this problem, or do I actually have to include my `Classes` folder inside my `Scripts` folder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: actually it does, ya. I think it is strange how python does not recognize relative pathes. But well.

Answer (score 0):

Place your modules in a package:

```
my_app
├── Scripts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myClass.py
├── Classes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myScript.py
└── __init__.py
```