# Import .py file to main file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried writing some commenly used function in a seperate file and import the same into mainApp file, but not able to use import.

I did find many questions regarding the this same question but, the solution was to keep the files in the same folder

[image]

I tried without .py as well, but the same error:

[image]
Can you please help me how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to say *what* error you are receiving. PyCharm automatically sets some module search paths, and the exact issue max depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

No '.py'. Just `import seperate`

Comment: you should set up the root directory first. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-content-roots.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in mainApp.py:

```
from seperate import *
a()
```

where seperate.py looks like this:

```
def a():
    print('hi')
```

Well, sorry, those two files need to be in the same folder. This is not a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of a relative import depends on the current location as well as the location of the module, package, or object to be imported. Here are a few examples of relative imports:

```py
from .some_module import some_class
from ..some_package import some_function
from . import some_class
```

[Read more about Absolute vs Relative Imports in Python](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)

In your case it should be:

```py
from .seperate import a
```

Also check this question:
[Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

add  your project directory into your path variable so that python know from where you want to import file