# How to import a file from a sibling directory in Python..?

Tags: python, import, package

How to import a file from a sibling  directory in Python..?

Eg.

1. Root> DirA>File1.py
2. Root>DirB>File2.py

I want to import File1.py into File2.py.

File2.py
from File2.py import abc

Thanks in advance..

Comment: check out [this answer from a previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506029)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can import `File1.py` into`File2.py` like below.

```
# File1.py
def func1():
    print("Function from File1.py")
```

```
# File2.py
import sys
sys.path.append("../DirA")
from File1 import func1

func1()
# >>> Function from File1.py
```