# İmport a python function inside a subfolder

Tags: python

I have a project folder called `Projects` and inside that folder I have a file called `my_functions.py`. Now I have a folder named `myProjects` and inside there is another python file called `test.py`

So it is something like

```
-Projects-
my_functions.py
    -myProjects-
     test.py
```

Now I have some functions in the `my functions` folder let me call them `f1`, `f2` etc.

Now, I need to take a function from `my_function.py` and use it inside the `test.py`

I have used things like

```
from my_functions import f1
from .my_functions import f1
from Projects.my_functions import f1
```

For the first one I get an error called

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_functions'
```

I have searched online and I find that I need to do something about `_init_.py` somewhere (?) The problem is, I am new in codding so I could not find where to put that module, in what way etc. So if someone can tell me what to do step by step it would be really helpful.

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfZUZ.png)

Here how it looks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages
Its clearly described. And its a double-underscore, be careful

Comment: I could not undersatnd it ..

Comment: You make `__init__.py` in the folder of your module you want to import.

Comment: @AlexanderRiedel It does not work

Answer (score 0):

you have to go up 1 directory.

```
from ..my_functions import f1
```

[the same question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: it says `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is inserting the folder's path. Now many computer scientist will get angry maybe for doing this but

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1,r'pathofcode')
```

then `from ... import ...` it will work.