# Being forced to import files relative to main.py in python

Tags: python

I've read several links about this but haven't been able to find something that addresses my situation.

Here's my directory structure:

```
- app

  - __init.py
  - main.py

  - foo
    - __init.py
    - foo_library.py

  - bar
    - __init.py
    -  bar_library.py
```

My application starts in `main.py` which in turn imports / calls all the other files.

However, it seems that I must import all files relative to `main.py`.

E.g inside `foo/foo_library`, if I want to import `bar/bar_library`, then I can't do `from ..bar import bar_library`, or `import app.bar.bar_library`.

Instead I must do `import bar.bar_library.py` - i.e the path that would work if I was importing it from `main.py` instead of `foo/foo_library.py`.

Is there any way to use `import app.bar.bar_library` or `from ..bar import bar_library`?

Comment: Try `relative imports` from [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Comment: top level scripts like `main.py` are not part of the package and should be placed in some other script directory. The package directory should be available on PYTHONPATH somewhere. Then, `main.py` will find the package based on normal python import rules. Normally I use [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html) to make a `setup.py` and install modules. Things are changing wtih [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/) so more reading may be required.

Comment: @LeonisSupreme I assume you mean `from ..bar import bar_library`? That doesn't work either

Comment: @LeonisSupreme -relative imports are fine within a package, but top level scripts like `main.py` aren't part of packages, so they don't work.

Comment: In your example, the package is `app`. Python adds the script directory to PYTHONPATH, so if you move `main.py` to the same directory that `app` is in, you can then do `import app` etc... in `main.py` and you can use relative imports within the package modules.

Comment: @tdelaney So if I moved `main.py` one level up and added the directory containing packages (called `app`) to sys.path, then `import app.foo.bar` would work from everywhere?

Comment: @tdelaney `main.py` *is* inside `app` right now but i can't do `app.bar.bar_library` inside `app.foo.foo_library`

Comment: @ClickUpvote - move `main.py` up, but don't add anything to `sys.path` - python will do that part for you. Then `import app.foo`. Now `foo_libary` can do `from ..bar import bar_library` because they are both part of the `app` package.

Comment: To be clear, I have `app/main.py` and inside `app/foo/foo_library.py` I want to import `app/bar/bar_library.py`

Comment: But `main.py` is not part of the package. It can import `foo` and `bar` because python adds the `app` directory to the python path. But if you do it this way, `foo` and `bar` are separate packages and you can't do relative imports with separate packages. You could have the bar code `import foo.whatever` (that is, use foo as a top level package), but that would mess up others who `import app` and try to use them as subpackages.

Comment: @tdelaney So I would move `main.py` up, then `import app.foo` inside `main.py`? And I'd also have to do `import app.bar` inside main.py if I wanted to import `bar_library` inside `foo_library`?

Comment: @tdelaney Actually, turns out I can't move main.py outside as I have a lot of other things going on (requirements.txt, .env, etc). Is there any way to make it work while keeping main.py where it is, e.g by adding the paths to sys.path?

Comment: If you write a `setup.py` and generate a distribution, you can mark `main.py` as an entry point. The installer will create a dummy `main.py` in the PATH that imports `app.main` and runs it. Its basically the same as if you ran `python3 -m app.main`. Now, since `main` is part of the package, it can do relative imports too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative imports only work within a single package. In your example, you have a package `app` with subpackages `foo` and `bar`. As long as a script or module imports `app` (e.g., `import app`), then modules in `foo` and `bar` can do relative imports.

Scripts are not in packages. This is the same model used generally with executables where the operating system is tasked with finding static dynamic libraries in a common LIB directory. So `main.py` has no inherent knowledge of the `app` package.

When python runs a script, it adds its path the `sys.path` so any module or directory in that path can be imported. In your case, `main.py` can `import foo` and `import bar`. But if you do that, `foo` and `bar` are separate packages and relative imports won't work between them.

You can solve the problem by moving `main.py` up one directory so that it can import `app`. More generally, you could move `main.py` into a script directory in your source tree and wrap your package + scripts into an installable distribution.

Another popular option when making a package installable, is to add entry point declarations to `setup.py`. The installer will add small dummy files in the operation system path that essentaily do `python3 -m app.main` to run the module within the package. Done this way, main.py is a part of the package and can do relative imports.

Comment: @ClickUpvote - there are several tricks. At the top of `main.py` you could add `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` which would add main's grandparent to the path, making `import app` work.