# How to perform Relative imports using Python

Tags: python

My dir looks like this

```
parentDir
    |__ app
    |    |__ main.py
    |
    |__ file.py
```

I'm in **main.py** and want to import a func in module **file.py**.
I have tried to do `from ../file import get_func` but I get an error

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My way does not work, any idea where I'm going wrong?

*I'm using python 3.8*

Comment: drop the slash. `from ..file import get_func`.

Comment: @AdamSmith When i do that i get ``ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package``. Any idea of a work around?

Comment: try - from parentDir.file import get_func

Comment: @AshishMJ I'm getting an error ``ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parentDir'`` when I do ``from parentDir.file import get_func``

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You first need to remove the /. Just do `from ..file import get_func`

Secondly, to import from file.py the package directory `parentDir` must be accessible from the Python module search path (sys.path)

So you need to add it to `sys.path` using `sys.path.append(path_of_parentDir)`

Comment: Nice. I’d recommend using `sys.path.insert(0, path)` as the import reads `sys.path` top to bottom, so to speak.