# Importing function in parent directory from ipynb

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

If I'm in a notebook thats stored in its own sub-dir, how can I call a function in the parent dir, or alternatively in an adjacent sub-dir (with both being within the parent directory)?

My directory structure is as follows:

```
main_dir/
  └─ __init__.py
  └─ main.py
  └─ my_funcs.py
  └─ sub_dir/
      └─demo.ipynb
```

When I try to run `from main_dir.my_funcs import func_name` from the demo notebook I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_dir'`. But when I run it from `main.py` it works correctly.

I had assumed that the `__init__.py` would mean that the notebook would automatically search and  find `my_funcs.py` but it seems I've missed something.

Comment: like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python

Comment: That gave me...  ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```

Comment: Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged. Consider changing the folder/file structure instead.

Comment: Thanks @alec_djinn - I've moved the demo notebook into the parent directory now and its working.