# ModuleNotFound using self made module/directory when running from the command line

Tags: python, module, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

I get the module not found error when importing my self made module.

Structure:

```
environment (folder/module to import)
project (folder)
-- project_scripts (folder)
   -- main_script.py
```

The problem is that I can run the main_script.py file from my text editor (pycharm) but not from the command line, then it gives the moduleNotFound error: no module named environment. Which is something I want to realize: running from the terminal.

The weird thing is that Pycharm gives type hints for the module, so it seems to recognize it. I am using an anaconda environment, but I made sure to activate it (in the terminal) and have set it as the Pycharm interpreter.

Details:
Python 3.8.16
The module has a **init** file

I hope someone could help me in the right direction, as I have been struggling more than 1 times with importing self-made modules to Python files, and struggled to find a consistent method.

I feel like it might have something to do with PYTHONPATH but im unsure as I don't have too much knowledge about this.

I tried different methods, such as changing the cwd to a different place (thought it would find the module in a different area) but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you launch python, it will include the current directory in its path and look for modules within and under it. I assume you are running your script using `python main_script.py` from the project_scripts folder? try running it from the environment folder as `python project/project_scripts/main_script.py`.

also, there are more SO questions regarding relative imports, see [How can I do relative imports in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-can-i-do-relative-imports-in-python) and [Importing from a relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505988/importing-from-a-relative-path-in-python)